# JFrame image clean while resizing

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt

I am painting random squares on the screen with double buffer but when I resize window frame cleans itself.  How may I stop this?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Do painting when told to do so.  That would be in the `paint(Graphics)` method of a `JFrame`.

Of course, better would be to put a `JPanel` in the frame.  The method to override would then become `paintComponent(Graphics)`.

Comment: I want to use active painting